# Adobe Flex4 mxml schema

Tags: apache-flex, xsd, flex4, mxml

Is there a MXML schema xsd given by the latest Flex4 distribution? I found from the old [release notes](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/1/releasenotes.html) that :

> Flex includes an XSD file that you can
>   integrate with your third-party
>   editing tools for schema validation
>   and easier MXML coding. This file is
>   installed in the following location:
>   {install.dir}/extras/schema/mxml.xsd

Answer (score 0):

There don't seem to be any extras included with the Flex 4 SDK, but some poking around turned up [this project](http://code.google.com/p/xsd4mxml/) to automatically generate the mxml.xsd.  It's geared towards Flex 3, but could be extended to Flex 4 if need be.